# How to change the required fields of review from true to false?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, review

When I review a product, there is a required field of `Review` on the last. I want to change this field from *required* to *not required*.

I changed this field for backend by editing `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php`.

```
$fieldset->addField('detail', 'textarea', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Review'),
    'required'  => false,
    'name'      => 'detail',
    'style'     => 'height:24em;',
));
```

Now I want to change it for frontend. How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$fieldset->addField('detail', 'textarea', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Review'),

            'name'      => 'detail',
            'style'     => 'height:24em;',
        ));
```

i just tried it and it working.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php
```

Comment: tried. Same result. Not working.

Comment: i remove 'required'  => true, on 127 line. that work

Comment: you are adding the review or editing the review?

Comment: i am adding a review from frontend.

Comment: got app/design/frontend/(yourtheme or base )/default/template/review/form.phtml  and remove class="required-entry" from line 85 or textarea field

Comment: i already that.
<label for="review_field"><?php echo $this->__('Review') ?></label>
                                                        <div class="input-box">
                                                            <textarea name="detail" id="review_field" cols="5" rows="3"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($data->getDetail()) ?></textarea>
                                                        </div>
It just removes "*" from "review" label.But when i click submit reviews, it shows on top "review can not be empty" after reloading the page.

Comment: app/code/core/mage/Review/Model/Review.php  comment 130 line      if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getDetail(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('review')->__('Review can\'t be empty');
        }

Comment: now i want to remove required field of zip/postal code from onpage checkout. any idea?

Comment: make file hidden and give some value..that is simple way

Comment: @QaisarSatti , pls see this :https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194959/connect-magentocommerce-com-core-to-upgrade-from-1-4-1-1-to-1-6

Answer (score 5):

go to the app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/form.phtml and replace this code

```
<label for="review_field" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Review') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
     <textarea name="detail" id="review_field" cols="5" rows="3" class="required-entry"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($data->getDetail()) ?></textarea>
</div>
```

with the below code

```
<label for="review_field"><?php echo $this->__('Review') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
    <textarea name="detail" id="review_field" cols="5" rows="3"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($data->getDetail()) ?></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: in that case, when i submit review, it says "review can not be empty".

Answer (score 1):

In Append to Piyush post. Remove validation from server side as below.

create a custom module and rewrite "Mage_Review_Model_Review" class as below.

In your custom module config.xml file. add below code under "models" node.

```
<global>
...........
....... 
...
<models>
  <modulename>
    <class>Your_Modulename_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>modulenam_mysql4</resourceModel>
  </modulename>
        <review>
            <rewrite>
                <review>Your_Modulename_Model_Review_Review</review>
            </rewrite>
        </review>
</models>
...........
.....
</global>
```

Now in Your "Your_Modulename_Model_Review_Review" model class add below code.

```
<?php
class Your_Modulename_Model_Review_Review extends Mage_Review_Model_Review
{


 public function validate()
{
    $errors = array();

    if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getTitle(), 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('review')->__('Review summary can\'t be empty');
    }

    if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getNickname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('review')->__('Nickname can\'t be empty');
    }
 // comment below code to remove details field valiation.
 //   if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getDetail(), 'NotEmpty')) {
  //      $errors[] = Mage::helper('review')->__('Review can\'t be empty');
  //  }
//
   if (empty($errors)) {
        return true;
    }
    return $errors;
   }
}
```