# What are all the tools available for checking Magento 2 coding standard?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, coding-standards

I am currently working on Magento 2 coding standard checking project.

Is any other tool available, other than [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer),  to check Magento 2 and PHP coding standing?

Comment: This article might help you a lot: https://go.adapttive.com/hLx39v

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Magento 2 use **ECGM2 coding standard**

You can download from here

> https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard

ECG Magento Code Sniffer Coding Standard is a set of rules and sniffs for **PHP_CodeSniffer** tool.

It allows automatically check your code against some of the common Magento and PHP coding issues, like:

1. raw SQL queries; SQL queries inside a loop;
2. direct instantiation of Mage and Enterprise classes;
3. unnecessary collection loading;
4. excessive code complexity;
5. use of dangerous functions; use of PHP Superglobals;

and many others.

1. Ecg for Magento
2. EcgM2 for Magento 2

Both Magento and Magento 2 are supported.

Comment: This tool is for extension for entire Magento 2 code check?

Comment: You can check Magento 2 module by this command after ECGM2 installation "phpcs --standard=EcgM2 /path/to/module"

Comment: Sure Patel. Any other tool available for please add in comments.

Comment: Shall i know W3C validation need for Magento 2 code validation?

Comment: W3C validation is for Magento Web Page Presentation, Not for coding standard. Magento use only ECG for both Magento 1 and 2 for checking extension coding standard.

Comment: I have tested my M2 module using ECGM2 Tool, in that they throw some warning &  errors, we resolve the error alone is enough?

Comment: @prince patel, is where we need to fix the error only or else need to fix the warning also?

Comment: @senthil You only need to fix critical errors. But it is best practice if you also fix the warning. Magento marketplace only checks critical errors to pass technical round. But keep practice to solve warnings to improve your coding standard.

Comment: @PrincePatel, thank for your update, I have fixed all the warning except the "Method Lenght is 106 Lines (20) allowed". this error showing in controller execute() method line, I just override core controller and update my logic in that execute() function, do you have any idea for fix the issue means kindly update it

Comment: @PrincePatel is there have any automatic error fixing command using the ECGM2?, is there have anything share it

Answer (score 12):

**Magento 2 use ECGM2 coding standard:**

1. **Install Coding Standard :**

   ```
   cd to/your/magento/install/directory
   composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com magento/marketplace-eqp magento-coding-standard
   composer require magento/marketplace-eqp
   cd magento-coding-standard
   ```

   If you get error:

   > PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHP_CodeSniffer_Exception: Referenced sniff "MEQP1.Exceptions.Namespace" does not exist

   ```
   vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../..
   vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set m2-path <path-to-magento2> ( for eg. sudo vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set m2-path  /var/www/html/magento2 )
   ```
2. **Test your M2 extension:**

   **To auto correct errors use phpcbf :**

   ```
   vendor/bin/phpcbf <path-to-magento2>/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/ --standard=MEQP2 --no-patch --extensions=php,phtml,xml,css,js
   ```

   **For View File**

   ```
   vendor/bin/phpcbf <path-to-magento2>/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates --standard=MEQP2 --extensions=php,phtml
   ```

   **To Check Error/ Warnnings :**

   ```
   vendor/bin/phpcs <path-to-magento2>/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/ --standard=MEQP2 --extensions=phtml,xml,css,js,php
   ```

   **For View File**

   ```
   vendor/bin/phpcbf <path-to-magento2>/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates --standard=MEQP2 --extensions=php,phtml
   ```

   **Solution for some warnings available here :**

   [How to fix warnings / errors raised by the Magento Marketplace technical review report?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111085/how-to-fix-warnings-errors-raised-by-the-magento-marketplace-technical-review)
3. **Marketplace Technical Review :**

   ```
   vendor/bin/phpcs /path/to/your/extension --standard=MEQP2 --severity=10
   ```
4. **Validate Magento 2 extension:**

   Download "validate_m2_package.php" from https://gist.github.com/alankent/fcf280dd9c599921b71d#file-validate_m2_package_v2-php and put it on root of magento:

   ```
   cd <path-to-magento2>
   php validate_m2_package.php Vendor_Module.zip
   ```

Comment: Before running `composer require magento/marketplace-eqp` fix it with this `composer config repositories.magento-eqp git https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp`. https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp/issues/2

Comment: https://go.adapttive.com/hLx39v

Answer (score 9):

In addition to [Prince Patels](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/177858/46249) answer ...

Magento 2 also [uses PSR-2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/coding-standards/code-standard-php.html) coding standard, so you can also run `phpcs --standard=PSR2 /path/to/module`. For fixing PSR-2 "errors" you can use "[PHP Code Beautifier and Fixer (phpcbf)](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Fixing-Errors-Automatically)"

For me this works very good ...

- fix PSR2 error automatically
- create reports
- merge reports into one file

Commands:

```
phpcbf --standard=PSR2 ./app/
phpcs --report-gitblame=CS-blame --report-source=CS-code --report-full=CS-full ./app/
cat CS-* >> ECG-PSR2 ; rm CS-*
```

If you use `git`, you can add a `pre-commit` [hook](https://gist.github.com/fdemiramon/0423b4308218d417fbf3) to run `phpcs`/`phpcbf` automatically before commiting your changes.

---

**Update:**

Not espaccially for magento coding standards, but good practice imho ...

- run `phpcbf` with `PSR2` and `MEQP2` standard
- run `phpcs -s` with both standards
- run `phpmd -s`
- run [`phpstan -l 7`](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan)

  - for magento 2.2 you have to use version `0.8.5`

<sup>`-s` option is to display sniff name ... maybe use ful if you want to supress warnings</sup>

For nice reports I'd suggest [phpdox](https://github.com/theseer/phpdox). It aggregates data from ...

- [`phploc`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc)
- `phpcs`
- `phpmd`
- `phpunit` code coverage
- git log
- ...

Sample (w/o code coverage): http://phpdox.de/demo/PHPUnit/index.xhtml

**Other tools:**

- [PHP Assumptions](https://github.com/rskuipers/php-assumptions)
- [PHP Magic Number Detector (PHPMND)](https://github.com/povils/phpmnd)
- [PhpMetrics](https://github.com/phpmetrics/PhpMetrics) with a cool class relation [diagram](http://www.phpmetrics.org/report/latest/relations.html) that helped me a lot

Comment: Thanks @sv3n. Any tool for check security?

Comment: For secuirty I've no tools. I think following coding standards (avoid raw queries and so on) is a first good step.

Answer (score 2):

To validate vulnerabilities of M2 application, we can use :

```
ZAP(Zed Attack Proxy).
```