# Use of protected class members is discouraged

Tags: magento2, module

I have tested my module2 module with **https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp**

I execute the following command

```
$ vendor/bin/phpcs /var/www/my/module --standard=MEQP2
```

I got the following warnings

```
Use of protected class members is discouraged.
Property name "$_pageFactory" should not be prefixed with an underscore to indicate visibility
```

My code is

```
protected $_pageFactory;
```

What should i do to remove those warnings?

I also got warning

```
Line exceeds 120 characters; contains 129 characters
```

How do i remove this warning?

Also got

```
"resource" is a reserved word in PHP 7
```

Code is `namespace Blaze\Intely\Model\Resource\Myorders;`
I create folder Resource inside model so i use Resource in namespace
I also search some examples they use Resource in namespace

Answer (score 0):

This are the general errors that are generated based on the standards. This errors itself tells what you need to change to fix them.

- change protected to public.
- remove underscore  change $_pageFactoryto $pageFactory
- Line exceeds 120 characters; contains 129 characters -> break the
  code of this line in more than one line (check the link I added below for better understanding).
- resource is reserved key word so use any other keyword in place of
     it.

for more errors and there solutions  please check awesome answer here-[How to fix warnings / errors raised by the Magento Marketplace technical review report?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111085/how-to-fix-warnings-errors-raised-by-the-magento-marketplace-technical-review)